# Using Bridge and Strategy together, is my idea correct/useful?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, orm

I'm working on a website project for a software engineering course. This site will be using a database to store data, currently through JDBC and MySQL.

Now the first thing I would want to do, is use the bridge pattern in order to decouple JCBC/MySQL from the implementation of the website, so that if in the future we decide to switch to another vendor (like Microsoft Server), it will be easier, "just" change the reference to the implementor class in the abstraction class.

At the same time, many of my classes use very similar functions on the databae. For example, I have three classes, TripControl, RouteControl, and LocationControl, and they each have a class they use to speak to the database(TripDB, RouteDB, LocationDB). So I was thinking, let's use the Strategy pattern, and have it so that TripControl, RouteControl, and LocationControl all talk to a Context class (using the book terminology here), and then use a Policy object to select which behaviour to use (TripPolicy for TripDB, RoutePolicy for RouteDB, LocationPolicy for LocationDB), this way it should make using the DB easy for the other devs (just choose the policy and forget about the rest).

Ok, so let's say I use the Strategy pattern, without the Bridge, and I switch from MySQL to MS Server (or I use both), I would need to have the following policies objects: TripPolicyMySQL, TripPolicyMS, RoutePolicyMySQL, RoutePolicyMS, RoutePolictyMySQL, RoutePolicyMS, to be able to choose which kind of database I'm working on. This makes it harder for the developers to implement their classes, and it looks (to me, at this moment at least), not really well suited to a change.

If I were to use the Strategy in conjunction with the Bridge, I should have something like this:

The developers have just three policy objects (LocationPolicy, RoutePolicy, TripPolicy), and they just use those. Then, on a lower level, the Strategy pattern will use the Bridge's interface(For example TripDB would be a bridge for TripDBMySQL and TripDBMS), which will hide the implementation of the database, which could be MS Server or MySQL.

Would doing this make any sense? I guess it's slower because of all the indirection, but it should make it easier on the developers and in theory it should make the system easier to exapnd.

Comment: A "correct" solution is any solution which passes the tests. I think the word you are looking for is "elegant". (not every correct solution is elegant and not every elegant solution is correct).

Comment: The only way to know if this makes sense is if the patterns are a good match for the specific problems you're trying to solve.  What are the specific problems you're trying to solve?

Comment: @RobertHarvey essentially the problem is the one I detailed in the question (a bit simplified for brevity)

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/102937) and respond.

Answer (score 3):

**Assessment of your design**

Decoupling the database dependent code from the website implementation is definitively a good idea here.  It is not fully clear however how you intend to use the bridge pattern:

- The [bridge pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/bridge-pattern.html) is about decoupling an abstraction from its implementation (using composition), so that the two may vary independently. But what's the abstraction and what's its implementation here ?  Is it really the kind of decoupling you're looking for ?
- I have the impression that your need is more about separating the presentation layer from the domain object management (Trip, Route, Location). For this you could consider an [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and [MVP](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/todd_snyder/archive/2007/10/17/mvc-or-mvp-pattern-whats-the-difference.aspx) or a [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) architecture.  These are all the combination of several design patterns (e.g. at least Observer and Command).

Refactoring your data management to reuse common behavior and isolate data table dependent behavior is also a good idea.  But I have serious doubts about the use of the strategy pattern for this purpose:

- The goal of a [strategy pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) is to be able to use strategies in an interchangeable manner. But you don't intend to use a `RoutePolicy` instead of a `TripPolicy` in an interchangeable manner in the same context (e.g. `RouteControler`), do you ?
- I think that you are more looking for factoring out the common behavior in some skeleton methods and vary some parts of it.  For this the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) seems more adapted.

**One step further ?**

You have analyzed your design using general purpose design patterns.  You could also consider more specialized [enterprise application patterns](http://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html).

From what you've told, the JDBC/MySQL part could end into some kind of [Table Data Gateway](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html), where a base `DataGateway` class would provide the common **data access** functionality and derived `TableXDataGateWay` classes could manage specific behavior/SQL commands for domain object `X`.  If you later decide to change database, everything you need to change is isolated in these classes.

With this logic in mind you could gain even greater decoupling, by having a [table module layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html) on the top of each table data gateway, in order to manage the **domain logic** (calculated fields, data validation, etc...).

Your webserver could then be structured to focus on **presentation** and user interaction (implementing an MVC, MVVM, or similar architectures, see above), the model part being here your table modules.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different and completely independent abstractions here:

1. what kind of data entity you are working with
2. what database technology you are using to get it

The problem with both of your approaches is that when you create a new entity, you need to create an implementation for each database. Likewise, if you add a new database, you need to add an implementation for every entity. That means the  work to add new features to your application will scale quadratically when it should ideally be linear.

It would make more sense when your data entities would be database-agnostic and your database bridges entity-agnostic.

You can achieve that by communicating through agnostic interfaces. All implementations of `IDatabaseEntity` call an `IDatabaseBridge` (which they receive at runtime through dependency injection), and all the methods of `IDatabaseBridge` take a `IDatabaseEntity` and are expected to work with any implementing class equally.

Congratulations, you just reinvented the [ORM Wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Answer (score 2):

First I think you should seriously consider if you really have the problem you are trying to solve.

The architecture you suggest will make it possible to switch database transparently, at runtime. Obviously this have a cost in complexity. So - do you really *need* to be able to switch database transparently, at runtime?

If you don't really need to hot-switch databases, but just want to avoid locking your self into a single database engine, then I suggest just separating the data access layer from the business layer. This will allow you to rewrite the DAL in the future or introduce hot-switching of database engines, *when it becomes necessary*.